# High CPU Temperature after switch to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, battery, cpu, temperature

The idle CPU Temp of my Intel i5-3210M CPU was ~40°C on Ubuntu 14.04.
Now, after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 (complete reinstall) it idles at ~52°C.

Battery lifetime is also noticeably lower.

What can I do? (What information is needed?)

Comment: Type `top`. Which processes are having hugh cpu usage?

Comment: Try to install TLP. It's awsome. http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/advanced-power-management-tool-tlp-sees.html

Comment: Firefox 100% CPU bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1576581  ?

Comment: Joakim Koed, I have TLP. These are the temperatures measured while tlp is running.

Comment: For me it was http://askubuntu.com/questions/775049/16-04-apt-update-never-ends --- check top and see if you have a rogue `appstreamcli` running at 100% CPU. (I know it's probably not the case, but I think that new user can get redirected here...)

Comment: Mine idled at 49°C on 14.04 but now 63°C on 16.04 . Also when just using Chrome the temperature is 65 - 70°C on 16.04 (previously it was 53 - 58°C). My room temperature is 30°C

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I ran the top command and the browser (vivaldi) is using the most cpu with up to 5 processes. The % range is between 1.5 to 7.0 without playing videos. The % range of the vivaldi browser playing videos is between 13.0 and 46.0. I'm not sure if has to do with ubuntu 16 or the vivaldi browser. I have no problems before with ubuntu 14.04.

I switched browsers (vivaldi, chromium, firefox) and the cpu's temperature incremented immediately within 90C.

#

I want to update this post. I couldn't find a solution running Ubuntu 16.04. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 and monitor the temperature. Firefox and Vivaldi still have problems raising the cpu temperature while playing videos. However, cpu temperature stays  between 60's and 70's playing videos with Chromium. I watched around one hour of a video tutorial and the cpu temperature was stable.
Looks like is a combination of OS and browser. The combination that works for me Ubuntu 14.04 and Chromium.
Hope Canonical developers gets notify about the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (after upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04). Psensors detected that my CPU's temperature is around 65° C.
I look at the top, which showed me that psensors are using about 93% of CPU. Then I tried to run configure psensors again (see http://itsfoss.com/check-laptop-cpu-temperature-ubuntu/)

> `sudo sensors-detect`
>
> `sensors`

Now I am observing significant decrease of CPU temperature (from 40° to 45°).

My configuration:
ThinkPad T440s, CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz, OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Unity

Answer (score -6):

The reason is because Ubuntu 16.04 does not use graphics. Now your CPU is doing all the heave lifting for the graphics.
Sadly they won't allow you to use vendor graphics drivers anymore.

Comment: Do you have sources for your statement?