# 16.04 apt update never ends

Tags: apt

It started few days ago. I'm running `sudo apt update` command and it never ends. Terminal output is

```
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94,5 kB]    
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:9 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Fetched 341 kB in 2s (150 kB/s)
```

While this proccess system fan speed is boosted on my laptop and it's kinda annoying to listen to this. There is no excessive cpu activity though. Can you guys hint me why it happens?

Comment: I have that problem as well since today (16.04) if i do run 'sudo apt update' or 'sudo apt-get update'. 'apt clean' doesnt help here. I do use other mirros then you - so its most likely not related with this aspect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bug. Look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712/. The problem is that the bug is affecting the update process, so you can't update. Catch 22.

So to solve it you have to manually install the broken packages.

If the system tried to do the update, you'll probably have a rogue `appstreamcli` running --- using 100% of your CPU; it will also have a lock held on the `apt` database, which will block any upgrade attempt.

To solve it, you have to kill the rogue `appstreamcli` ---  ypu can find its PID by running top, and then

```
sudo kill <PID here>
```

The second step is to manually update the failing packages as in: (**Notice: on a 64-bit system; if you run a 32 bit system you must change the links accordingly, using `i386` in lieu of `amd64`**)

```
cd /tmp && mkdir asfix
cd asfix
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

as posted in comment #24 of the bug report.

Now you can update your system; once you successfully do that, you can safely remove the downloaded packages.

Nice bug.

BTW --- this is the same as [appstreamcli hanging with 100% CPU usage during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774986/appstreamcli-is-cooking-my-laptop-what-is-it-ubuntu-16-04)  and [apt-get is stuck at "Fetched XXKb in XXsec"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774918/apt-get-is-stuck-at-fetched-xxkb-in-xxsec)

Comment: Can I remove the folder and debs after I install them?

Comment: @JulianLai yes, see the edit.

Comment: Looks like the first step of killing appstreamcli is optional... it wasn't running on my system. The rest worked and fixed my update problem. Thanks.

Comment: @stmax yes, see the edit...

Comment: Sad, so many bugs since 16.04 ...

Comment: @EdiD well, this is the reason that by default the LTS update is offered by default only for 16.04.1 --- we are doing a bit of community ironing out bug effort here.

Comment: Yeah exactly but IMHO this ironing should be on the beta stage

Comment: I'm relieved that I can still use the brute-force method and just reinstall from a stick. I'm pretty careful to keep all my work in the cloud, and that policy pays off at times like this. Reinstalling apps isn't too bad, especially since that makes sure I have current versions on everything.